# Infering sObject Type from Id or collection of Id's

Tags: apex, trigger, sobject

If I have an instance of an Id variable that has been populated with a value, is there way to infer the sObject type of that Id using a describe call.

So if I did:

```
Set<id> parentIds = new Set<id>();

for (Attachment a : Trigger.new){
   parentIds.add(a.ParentId);
}

//and here, I want to find out what are the parent records of these attachments.
```

Presuming all ParentId values are identical sObject types, is there anything I can do to check this?

And a follow-on: Can I infer sObject type from Id instance at all? Seems that could be handy at times.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

in APIv26 there's a new method, [Id.getSObjectType()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm) which returns a sObject token you can use to find it's type. Sample code:

```
String objectAPIName = someId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```

This new style uses much less heap space and <del>script statements</del>CPU time in addition to being much simpler and is highly recommended.

---

**Don't do this anymore**, but traditionally you could use the global describe to check the key prefix of each sObject type against your record Id and if they matched you knew what type of record it is. A sample of doing this (shamlessly stolen from [Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett)):

```
String myIdPrefix = String.valueOf(someId).substring(0,3); //get just the prefix
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = 
Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
for(Schema.SObjectType stype : gd.values())
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = stype.getDescribe();
    String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
    System.debug('Prefix is ' + prefix);
    if(prefix!=null && prefix.equals(myIdPrefix))
    {
        System.debug('Stop hammer time! ' + r.getName());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve the above using any of salesforce REST based APIs?

Comment: Via the API I think the best thing you can do is check the key prefix from the global describe. Should be somewhat similar to the first code block in my answer - just using the api instead of apex methods to get the global describe.

Comment: You might want to edit the `getSObjectType` method to be more prominent in your post.

Comment: if (childRecord.ParentId != null && childRecord.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Case.getSObjectType()) {

Comment: Hi @ca_peterson, I know this is a really old post but I was curious what are your thoughts on this [PMD rule](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_performance.html#eagerlyloadeddescribesobjectresult) warning `anIdProperty.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();` being fired when using this method.

Comment: @Jose is your apex class using an old API version? on newer API versions getDescribe() defaults to a deferred mode that's substantially faster, which is what this rule looks to be flagging.

Comment: @ca_peterson it's happening regardless of the API version we use (we are currently using API version 56.0, we recently updated all the metadata).