# Generic SObject update pattern

Tags: apex, sobject, dml, describesobject

### Question

I know that it is possible to update a generic of `List<SObject>`, But what is the best approach to generate that list without knowing the SObjectType, only the ids ?

### Sample:

```
 List<SObject> l = new List<SObject>();
 
 SObject o1 = new SObject(id='xxxxxx'); //this Id could be an Account
 o1.Name = 'Test';
 l.add(o1);


 SObject o2 = new SObject(id='xxxxxx'); //this Id could be a Custom
 o2.Name = 'Test' 
 l.add(o2); 
 
 //this is possible
 update l;
```

Unfortunately, SObject constructor doesn't allow id as parameter.

### Backgound:

I'm trying to make a generic WS which will receive a list of objects to update( or upsert). The received object could by any type.

*WS Request sample:*

```
  [
   {id:'xxxxx',Name:'Test'},
   {id:'yyyyy',Name:'Test 2'},
   {id:'zzzzz',Name:'Test 3'}
  ]
```

The id attribute cloud be from any SObject.( I know the extra attr to update always exist).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What exactly is the web service receiving?

Comment: @MikeChale I've updated my question adding a request sample

Comment: Couldnt you use the ID key prefix to determine what the type of SObject was?

Comment: I though so, looks like @amatorVitae used this prefix method.  Beat me to typing it out  lol

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Once you have the sObjectType you should be able to construct the sObject instance using the [`sObjectType.newSObject(ID Id)`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_SObjectType_newSObject_2.htm) method. You can get the sObjectType from the Id using the  [Id.getSObjectType()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Id_getSObjectType.htm) method;

```
Map<Id, String> idsToUpdate = new Map<Id, String>();

// Put the Id's and associated name values in the map

List<SObject> sObjectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();

for (Id idToUpdate : idsToUpdate.keySet()) {
    SObject o1 = idToUpdate.getSObjectType().newSObject(idToUpdate);
    // Set the Name field dynamically
    o1.put('Name', idsToUpdate.get(idToUpdate));
    sObjectsToUpdate.add(o1);
}

update sObjectsToUpdate;
```

Comment: Incredible answer, This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: When I try this sample code, I'm getting `Variable does not exist: Name`. Have any idea why?

Comment: @user3850805 I've changed the code to use a dynamic `put` to set the Name field.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to a post that I think answers your question:  [Infering sObject Type from `Id` or collection of `Id`'s](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/infering-sobject-type-from-id-or-collection-of-ids)

Essentially, the solution entails:

1. Pulling the sObject "prefix" (the first 3 characters) from the `id` you receive
2. Get the `sObjectType` so you can cast your objects as the corresponding `sObject` (or `list<yourSobject__c>`)
3. Upsert the typed-records

Link to [SF Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_namespace_Schema.htm)

---

Here's a Utility Method I wrote that writes a query to select ALL fields from an sObject by only giving the string value of the Object `Name`.  It exemplifies finding an sObject's metadata (in this case, its `fields`).

```
public static string FormatFieldsForQuery(string objectName,string prefix){
    if(string.isNotBlank(prefix)){
        if(prefix.endsWith('__c'))
            prefix=prefix.replace('__c','__r.');   
        if(!prefix.endsWith('.'))
            prefix+='.';
    }
    string fields = '';
    sObjectType objectType=Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    if(objectType==null)
        return fields;
    for(string f :objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet())
        fields+=prefix+f+',';
    return fields.removeEnd(',');  
}//END FormatFieldsForQuery(string objectName,string prefix)
```

Comment: Based on @DanielBallinger comment , your answer and @ca_peterson answer, I think this is possible: `Sobject o1 = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(myId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()).newSObject(myId);` , isn't ?.... One line will solve my problem, sounds awsome

Comment: @MartinBorthiry Sorry, I deleted my comment as I wanted to expand on it as a separate answer. IMHO amatorVitae still deserves the credit for getting the answer.

Comment: @amatorVitae thanks for this approach, It was the base for the best solution. My up vote here